# What is Target in C#? Where can I use target?

Tags: c#

The program is executing, but I have a little knowledge in interfaces and how to use them. In CompareTo method implementation, I found target and double diff, I quite couldn't get them. I understood till the CompareTo method.

```
 class Polygon
public virtual void Draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drawing Polygon");
        }
interface IComparable
    {
        int CompareTo(object obj);
    }
     class Program:Polygon,IComparable
    {
        private double Length { get; set; }
        private double Width { get; set; }
        public override void Draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drawing: Rectangle");
        }
        public double GetArea()
        {
            return Length * Width;
        }
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 1;
            if (!(obj is Program))
                throw new ArgumentException();
            Program target = (Program)obj;
            double diff = this.GetArea() - target.GetArea();
            if (diff == 0)
                return 0;
            else if (diff > 0)
                return 1;
            else return -1;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Program rect1 = new Program { Length = 10, Width = 20 };
            Program rect2 = new Program { Length = 100, Width = 200 };
            Console.WriteLine(rect1.CompareTo(rect2));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `target` is a reference to `obj` after casting to `Program` so you can access `GetArea`.

Answer (score 4):

`target` is a variable of type `Program` which is a class. This variable is within the function `CompareTo` so it can only be referenced within the function and after it is declared and defined i.e: `Program target = (Program)obj;`

It appears you need to revisit an introductory textbook or online course in C#.

Comment: It would be clearer to say it's a variable, IMO. Differentiating between variables, their values, references and objects is important - it's not like using the method creates the instance.